# Local homeomorphism and coverings

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a local homeomorphism with X, Y connected, locally path connected, Hausdorff and with X also compact. Then f is also a covering with finite fibers.

I know how to show that the fibers are finite.
Given that f is a surjection, I know how to show that f is a covering map.

**How do I show that f is surjective?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have it. The image of X under f is open (use "local homeomorphism") and closed (use "compact" and "Hausdorff") in Y and since Y is connected this shows that the image is the whole of Y.